# Processing speed for swapExactETHForTokens vs swap

Tags: uniswap, swaps

Is there a difference in transcation processing speed in UniswapV2 when using a swap function versus using the swapExactETHForTokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "swap" function in Uniswap. All swaps are executed through one of the functions in the Router - such as `swapExactETHForTokens`.

Furthermore, processing speed is an irrelevant measurement in Ethereum blockchain. The processing time is a miniscule amount of time compared to waiting for your transaction to be mined. You can just forget about any concept of processing speed. The only metrics you should be interested in is the transaction's gas usage.